# Error when accessing Facebook API posts_insights

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am an admin for a page for which I am trying to get posts insights. I am also developer of the app which is accessing this data. I authorised read_insights permission using Open Graph Explorer and successfully got access token. I am trying the following call in Open Graph Explorer:

`page_id/posts_insights?since=1432481806&until=1433085606`

and it returns me this:

`{
  "error": {
    "message": "An unknown error has occurred.", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}`

I know that read_insights permission needs to be reviewed by Facebook before releasing the app to the public, but in the past other permissions which also needed to be reviewed worked for app testers and developers even without Facebook review.

Comment: That sounds like a bug - you should file a bug report in Facebook's Bug tracker ( https://developers.facebook.com/bugs )

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/834574419958833/